# How to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \lVert T^n \rVert_K ^{\frac{1}{n}}$ exists, where $\lVert T \rVert_K=\inf_{S \in L_c(X,X)} \lVert T+S \rVert$?

Tags: operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $L(X,X)$ the space of bounded linear operator on $X$ and $L_c(X,X)$ the space of compact linear operator on $X$. Given $T \in L(X,X)$ define $\lVert T \rVert_K=\inf_{S \in L_c(X,X)} \lVert T+S \rVert$.
How can i show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \lVert T^n \rVert_K ^{\frac{1}{n}}$ exists? Has $\lVert \cdot \rVert_K$ the submultiplicative property?

Answer (score 1):

You have that $\|T\|_K=\|\pi(T)\|$, where $\pi$ is the quotient map onto the Calkin algebra. This immediately gives you the submultiplicativity.

And $\lim_n\|\pi(T)^n\|^{1/n}=\operatorname{spr}(\pi(T))$, where spr denotes the spectral radius. So the limit is the essential spectral radius.